# Multilingual CMS website in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, multilingual

I'm working on wordpress CMS website.
Basically I want this website in 2 different languages(say English and Japanese).

Now Main Point is, I **DO NOT** wan't to go for any Localization Plugins.
Admin will write down and update content for both languages.

What can be the best possible way to make this work?

Do I have to create two sub sites for each language? or suggest me any alternative way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wordpress is single langauge by default (it has one screen language and it does not differ languages for posts and pages). If you don't want to use plugins, use two sites.

Comment: Thank for the reply hakre. Yes initially I was planning to have 2 websites but if there is any alternative to avoid this scenario, will be grateful to know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had this problem further back and we created **two sub domains** eventually and it worked (like us.example.com  and uk.example.com). The CMS we were using did not support i18n...I think that since you are working with 2 different languages maintaining 2 different sites **does not give that big overhead** for maintenance because they differ in every way including the URL structure.

Answer (score 1):

Still you have to be more clear to choosing the way for multilingual.Hope this helps.

1) If you need just your post & pages to be get translated manually use [qTranslate](http://www.qianqin.de/qtranslate/) .

2) If you need everthing change including your widgets & plugins than you must have to use 2 wordpress setup or [WPML](http://wpml.org/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are up for writing your own WP theme (not that hard) all you have to do is use a different category for each language, and then pull the appropriate content in the theme, based on detecting the language code category in the URL.

I like to remove both the category and tag base from the URL, so the language follows right after the domain name.

I've just finished writing a fully automated site in English/Chinese and every single thing is in its own language, including the AJAX contact form. No messy plugins required. No language switching. Just a single theme. It is way simpler in my opinion than messing with WPML and things like that. But you do need to know PHP.

Answer (score 0):

use WordPress multisite install.